# Is there any way to tap on iconWidget in OpenStreetMap (flutter_osm_plugin)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, openstreetmap

I am using [flutter_osm_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_osm_plugin) to show my map. And in **StaticPositionedGeoPoint** i'm giving iconWidget. Which is having inkwell itself. But some how I am not able to tap on marker.

```
for (int i = 0; i < latlngList.length; i++) {
  markers.add(StaticPositionGeoPoint(
      i.toString(),
      MarkerIcon(
          iconWidget: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("Marker Tapped");
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.pink),
        ),
      )),
      latlngList));
}
```

Anyone know how to achieve this?